# Force keyboard focus to LineEdit QT

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyside

I'm trying to develop an overlay PopUp for Windows that's triggered by a global keybind, which should capture focus into a QLineEdit once the keybind is pressed. The issue is that if it was focused once, but I click outside effectively removing focus, the focus can't be reacquired afterward.

This is a simplified version of the code I'm trying to use to force keyboard focus on the QLineEdit:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from pynput import keyboard

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.input)

        self.input.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def toggle_visible(self):
        if self.isVisible():
            print("Hiding popup")
            self.hide()
        else:
            print("Showing popup")
            self.show()
            self.activateWindow()
            self.input.grabKeyboard()
            self.input.setFocus()

class KeybindPressed(QtCore.QObject):
    keybind_pressed = QtCore.Signal()

    def __call__(self):
        self.keybind_pressed.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    pressed = KeybindPressed()
    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<alt>+<space>": pressed}):

        widget = MyWidget()
        pressed.keybind_pressed.connect(widget.toggle_visible)
        widget.resize(800, 600)
        widget.show()

        app.exec()
```

This is a recording showing the undesired behaviour of the focus staying in the other app instead of returning to the window when showing.

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mre], not external links

Comment: Unfortunately, on Windows, this behaviour is "by design". The OS actively prevents focus-stealing, as stated in the [docs for activateWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#activateWindow). Qt provides [QWindowsWindowFunctions.setWindowActivationBehavior](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindowswindowfunctions.html#setWindowActivationBehavior) as a work-around this, but neither PyQt nor PySide implements the `QWindowsWindowFunctions` class.

Comment: It looks like it might be possible to roll your own solution using the win32api. I'm on Linux (which doesn't have this issue) so I can't test any of this, but there's [an article here](https://www.semicolonworld.com/question/59422/windows-7-how-to-bring-a-window-to-the-front-no-matter-what-other-window-has-focus) with a possible solution. If that doesn't work, you could try porting Qt's [QWindowsWindow::requestActivateWindow](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/plugins/platforms/windows/qwindowswindow.cpp.html#2498) function.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you, that did it! im able to now force focus. writing answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [ekhumoro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/984421/ekhumoro) i was able to figure out how to force focus on windows. Below is the code needed to force focus:

imports and setup

```py
windows = False
if os.name == "nt":
    import win32gui, win32con, win32process, win32api
    win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, win32con.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE | win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE)
    windows = True
```

code to actually force focus, this would be called when your window should get focus:

```py
def force_focus(qt_widget_instance: QtWidgets.QWidget):
    if windows:
        fgwin = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        fg = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgwin)[0]
        current = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
        if current != fg:
            win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, current, True)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(qt_widget_instance.winId())
            win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, win32api.GetCurrentThreadId(), False)
```

And here is the full example with this implemented:

```py
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from pynput import keyboard

import os

windows = False
if os.name == "nt":
    import win32gui, win32con, win32process, win32api
    win32gui.SystemParametersInfo(win32con.SPI_SETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT, 0, win32con.SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE | win32con.SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE)
    windows = True

def force_focus(qt_widget_instance: QtWidgets.QWidget):
    if windows:
        fgwin = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
        fg = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(fgwin)[0]
        current = win32api.GetCurrentThreadId()
        if current != fg:
            win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, current, True)
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(qt_widget_instance.winId())
            win32process.AttachThreadInput(fg, win32api.GetCurrentThreadId(), False)

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.input = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.input)

        self.input.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.ApplicationModal)
        self.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowActive)
        self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
    
    @QtCore.Slot()
    def toggle_visible(self):
        if self.isVisible():
            print("Hiding popup")
            self.hide()
        else:
            print("Showing popup")
            self.show()
            force_focus(self)
            self.activateWindow()
            self.input.grabKeyboard()
            self.input.setFocus()



class KeybindPressed(QtCore.QObject):
    keybind_pressed = QtCore.Signal()

    def __call__(self):
        self.keybind_pressed.emit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    pressed = KeybindPressed()
    with keyboard.GlobalHotKeys({"<cmd>+<space>": pressed}):
    
        widget = MyWidget()
        pressed.keybind_pressed.connect(widget.toggle_visible)
        widget.resize(800, 600)
        widget.show()

        app.exec()
```