# Pyqt5 | How to properly combine multiple windows in one app

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have an application that consists of multiple uis(windows) and a main script, that should tie them all together into one program. Here is the video showing it: https://youtu.be/B4-PKmbyvjY.

The first problem is that when the active window changes, the application icon on the taskbar flashes. And it's very annoying. The second problem is that my computer is quite strong, and the delay between switching windows is not particularly noticeable. But when my friend started this program on his laptop, the delay between hiding one window and opening another was huge. For a whole second there was a desktop instead of the program. And so it is with every window switch.

Here's a main.py script:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot

from downloadPage import DownloadPage
from mainPage import MainPage
from managerPage import ManagerPage
from registrationPage import RegistrationPage
from loginPage import LoginPage


QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling, True)
QApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_UseHighDpiPixmaps, True)


def switch(_from, _to):
    # Open new window on the position of the last opened window
    # Otherwise it just appears in the center
    lastPos = _from.pos()
    modifiedPos = (lastPos.x() + _from.width() // 2,
                   lastPos.y() + _from.height() // 2)
    newPos = (modifiedPos[0] - _to.width() // 2,
              modifiedPos[1] - _from.height() // 2)

    _to.move(*newPos)
    _to.show()
    _from.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    # Pages (uis)
    registerWin = RegistrationPage()
    mainWin = MainPage()
    downloadWin = DownloadPage()
    managerWin = ManagerPage()
    loginWin = LoginPage()
    mainWin.show()

    # Switch windows on button clicks
    loginWin.registerButton.clicked.connect(
        lambda: switch(loginWin, registerWin))
    registerWin.loginButton.clicked.connect(
        lambda: switch(registerWin, loginWin))
    mainWin.downloadButton.clicked.connect(
        lambda: switch(mainWin, downloadWin))
    mainWin.browseButton.clicked.connect(
        lambda: switch(mainWin, managerWin))

    downloadWin.returnButton.clicked.connect(
        lambda: switch(downloadWin, mainWin))

    # After register/login was successful
    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def successfulLogin(login):
        mainWin.upperText.setText(
            f'Welcome, {login}! What brings you here today?')
        switch(registerWin, mainWin)

    registerWin.successfulRegister.connect(successfulLogin)
    loginWin.successfulLogin.connect(successfulLogin)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've heard about QTabWidget, but i'm not quite sure if it's the solution in my case. There should be buttons to switch between tabs and my program just can't allow that.
Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: Why do you move the windows every time? Set the default geomtery in the `__init__` for each window, and then just hide the current window and show the new one. It's nicer to keep the geometry the user wants.

Comment: No, the geometry stays the same. New window just matches previous window center position. That's all. Personally i find it uncomfortable, when the window is placed randomly every time. https://imgur.com/a/sKhhe0O

Comment: But it's not random. Calling `show()` after `hide()` should keep the current geometry. There's no need to reset it every time.

Comment: Re: taskbar flashing - try [setWindowActivationBehavior](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwindowswindowfunctions.html#setWindowActivationBehavior).

Comment: Well, In the case of a single window, yes. But as you can see it can't synchronize multiple windows.

Comment: Let the user decide. Anyway, you will need to test it on the user's system to see if it makes any difference. And also try disabling the DPI settings.

Comment: How can i import QWindowsWindowFunctions in pyqt? I can only find examples of importing it in c++

Comment: I assumed it must be available in PyQt on Windows (I have no way of testing it myself). But maybe it's not possible to wrap it.

Comment: If you want a single window that always appears with the same geometry, you can try [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html). That will eliminate the hide/show (and probably the taskbar flashing as well).

Comment: What about using QStackedWidget? You'll need to apply some fixes (most importantly, its size hint), but that should do exactly what you mean.

Comment: Actually, it seems I have investigated `QWindowsWindowFunctions` before, but completely forgot about it. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68764703/984421).